# index is not changing in every loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, foreach

I want to have a function call for every number in an array. I also want some values to depend on what number of loop you are on (index) and what number you are on. (item). It successfully determines which item i am on, so I did not include that part of code but the index one always shows up as zero even though its on the second or third loop. If I console.log beat it always shows up as eb1b05, and if i console.log index it always shows up as zero

```
function foreachfunction(item, index){

let intervals = [fifthfunction, fourthfunction];
    
    let interval = intervals[Math.floor(Math.random() * intervals.length)]
    interval();

    
    if(interval == fifthfunction){
    findnotefifth()
    }
    if(interval == fourthfunction){
    findnotefourth()
    }

function findnotefifth(){
    let beat = eb1b05

    if (index == 0){
        beat = eb1b05

    }
    if (index == 1){
        beat = eb1b1

    }
    if (index == 2){
        beat = eb1b15

    }
    if (index == 3){
        beat = eb1b2
    }
}
function findnotefourth(){
    let beat = eb1b05

    if (index == 0){
        beat = eb1b05

    }
    if (index == 1){
        beat = eb1b1

    }
    if (index == 2){
        beat = eb1b15

    }
    if (index == 3){
        beat = eb1b2
    }

}
console.log(beat)
console.log(index)
}
```

Comment: Share the foreach loop code

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to achieve, but I'm sure these consecutive if's are not good design. Whatever you want to do, there's most probably a very short and much more efficient answer

Comment: @dev55555     bar1beats.forEach(foreachfunction);

Comment: There is absolutely no way we can help you if you don't share your full code with us. if eb1b1 is not a variable, your syntax is wrong, and if it is we don't see it defined. Same thing for fifthfunction or fourthfunction. Additionally you should take the habit of putting a semicolumn at the end of every line, even if not stricto sensu mandatory.